# Factory method UML diagram clarification

Tags: design-patterns, uml, factory-method

I was going through the factory method pattern describe [here](http://exciton.cs.rice.edu/JavaResources/DesignPatterns/book/hires/pat3cfso.htm). I didn't quite get the meaning of the arrows marked from `Application` to `Document` and from `MyApplication` to `MyDocument`. Can anyone help to me to understand this notation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation between `Application` and `Document` is an ***Aggregation***. It means that an `Application` (Whole) contains `Documents` (Parts).

The relation between `MyApplication` and `MyDocument` is a ***Dependency***. It means that MyApplication may change when MyDocument changes. In this case it is a <> Dependency, i.e. `MyApplication` uses `MyDocument`

Comment: If it is contains, isn't is called Composition?

Comment: Composition is a different symbol. Composition means that the Whole is completely responsible for the part, i.e. for creating and destroying it. Which means if the the Whole is destroyed, the Part will be gone, too. See http://ootips.org/uml-hasa.html for details.